# Probability of 2 n-bit binary strings lining up, given that the first k bits do so

Tags: probability, binary

There are two rows of 10,000 bits, one on top of the other, currently all set to 0.

00000000000000000...
00000000000000000...

Now imagine that in each row, 40 of the bits are randomly flipped to a 1.
My question is, given that the first 20 ones in the top row line up perfectly with the first 20 in the bottom row: (probably a lot more spaced out with 10,000 indices)

0100000110001010010...
0100000110001010010...

what is the probability that ALL of the 40 bits that are 1 in the top row occur in the same indices as the ones in the bottom row?

More generally, if k bits out of n total (n > k) are randomly flipped to one, and it is given that the first x ones occur in the same place in each row, what is the chance that all k ones occur in the same place? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider the $1$'s in the top string fixed and count the number of ways to place the $1$'s in the lower string.  There are $10,000-20$ bits which are unknown.  Of those exactly $20$ are $1$'s.  There are $\binom{10,000-20}{20}$ ways to put those $1$'s into the bottom string.  Each of those placements are equally likely... and only 1 of those lines up perfectly with the top string.

Can you take it from here?

In general, if there were $N$ bits total, $n$ bits to be $1$'s and $k$ bits already set to $1$, then instead of $\binom{10,000-20}{20}$ you would have $\binom{N-k}{n-k}$.

Comment: Hmm, so the actual example that I'm reading about used 200 instead of 40, but the article claimed that if you look at just 20 of the 200 1's, the chances of the other 180 not lining up is incredibly small when considering a 10000 bit string. However, when I do the math as you suggest, I get an astronomically high chance of the 180 not lining up

Comment: @Phylth, If there are $10,000-20$ options to place $180$ more $1$'s, then the chances they line up will be $\frac{1}{\binom{10,000-20}{180}}$ which is a really, really, really small number.  Most calculators (Ti-89 possibly exempt) will just call this $0$.

Comment: Perhaps the text got large and small mixed up.  There is a small chance they will line up... a large chance that they will not (not all of them at least).

Comment: Is there maybe a condition that we're missing here?

Comment: @Phylth, are the bit flips chosen uniformly at random? i.e. is any set of $40$ (or $200$ from comments) bits equally likely to be chosen?  or is there some kind of dependence?  Like having a MASK and just selecting where the first bit of the MASK lines up...

Comment: @Phylth, what book/text/article are you reading?  If you can give me enough info about the name/author/etc, I can possibly find the article and take a look.

Comment: I wish I could be more helpful. The problem comes from a neural network implementation where 200 active bits out of 10000 represents a pattern. The paper says that, because the patterns are "large and sparse", only 20 or so of the active bits in a pattern need to be remembered in order to recognize the pattern with a negligible chance of error. It's a memory saving technique apparently. Can you guys think of any modification to my problem that would entail this kind of outcome?

Comment: @TravisJ its HTM Cortical Learning Algorithms by Numenta, the problem is well stated on page 29 under the "Temporal Pooler Concepts" heading. http://numenta.org/resources/HTM_CorticalLearningAlgorithms.pdf

Comment: @Phylth, It seems like they are assuming there are relatively few possible configurations of the 1's... not all $2^{10,000}$ possibilities.  With the assumption that there are maybe only millions of "reasonable" sets of 200 1's, then given that you've matched 20, it is likely that the rest is a match (because most of the sets of 200 don't overlap by much).  There are definitely some underlying assumptions they are making that they do not make clear on this page.

Comment: I'm thinking it could be that, similar to what you said, only a relatively small number of patterns are stored in memory and so they are unlikely to overlap much

Comment: @Phylth, not just stored in memory, but only a few patterns ever occur...

Comment: Here's another related problem: Let there be n 10,000 bit strings (let's say n=10), each with 200 1's in random places. Perform an OR on all the strings to get a single 10,000 bit string (the union of the n strings). Now generate another random 10,000 bit string with 200 1's; I want to see if it is contained in the "union string". If the first 20 1's in the new string are also 1's in the "union string", what is the chance that the new string was not one of the original strings that was unioned? Is this more revealing?